# JPlayer with .flv files

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I hate using these because I can never find a tutorial for them.

I have a `jPlayer` that I am trying to use to play `.flv` video files. I have been looking for a tutorial on how to use `jPlayer` but everything I can find is either complete garbage, or does not show any code what so ever, just the end product (very helpful, I know).

Here is how I make my `jPlayer`:

```
//Creates the JPlayer for that video
$('#videoPlayerDiv').jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            flv: videoLocation
        }).jPlayer("play");
    },
    supplied: "flv",
    swfPath: "jPlayer/js"
});
```

`videoLocation` is a location to each video file. I have already tested the location and it is correct. When I run the page I get the video box to show up, but I cannot get it to play, or show any video file location.

If anyone can find an issue (or a tutorial) that would help me out a lot.

Comment: what is the content of videoLocation? can you give an example URL?

Comment: Its uploaded from a server. I can't give the full location but its something along these lines: `http://mytabs/tabs/our_tabs/our_solutions/videos/myvideos.flv`

Comment: Do you have to use jPlayer for this? I've never used jPlayer for video, I use flowplayer personally.

Comment: I don't have to use jPlayer. If there was an easier way I would rather do that

Comment: Try looking into flowplayer, I use that to play FLV files.

Comment: Yea I think I am going to give that a try instead and see if i can get it to work or not

Comment: I tried Flowplayer and I got it to work in about 2 minutes. Make that an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#videoPlayerDiv').jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        this.element.jPlayer("setFile","path/to/flv/video/file.flv");
    }
});
```

EDIT:
OP decided to use flowplayer instead of jPlayer.

Comment: That worked out a little better. It appears (I'm not completely sure) that the video file is loaded into the player, but it still wont play (I did `this.element.jPlayer("setFile","path/to/flv/video/file.flv").play();` thought)

Comment: Does your play function look similar to this?
`$("#play").click(function() {
 $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer("play");
 showPauseBtn();
 return false;
});`

Comment: I didn't have a play (I didn't know you needed it) but I tried and it still wouldn't play. Here is how it looked:   `function playVideo(videoLocation) {  //Creates the JPlayer for that video
    $('#videoPlayerDiv').jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            this.element.jPlayer("setFile", videoLocation).play();
        }
    });

    $("#play").click(function () { $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer("play"); showPauseBtn(); return false; });
}`

Comment: That gave me a black screen with no buttons on it, and clicking it would not cause it to play

Comment: Have you tried replacing the flv file with an mp3 file to see if it loads audio fine?

Comment: Not an mp3 but I have tried an m4v (and edited the code to pretty much exactly copy a tutorial i found). That didn't work either. I just keep getting a black box

Answer (score 0):

here is another answer that worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <link href="http://jplayer.org/latest/skin/pink.flag/jplayer.pink.flag.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jplayer.org/2.1.0/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        /*paste or reference your JS here*/

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>

    <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
        <div class="jp-type-single">
            <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
                <ul class="jp-controls">

                    <!-- comment out any of the following <li>s to remove these buttons -->

                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- you can comment out any of the following <div>s too -->

                <div class="jp-progress">
                    <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                    <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                <div class="jp-duration"></div>                   
            </div>
            <div class="jp-title">
                <ul>
                    <li>Cro Magnon Man</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-no-solution">
                <span>Update Required</span>
                To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>



$(document).ready(function() {

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function(event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            flv:"http://www.website.com/videos/training_videos/Buying_Online_vs_Buying_From_Talent_Advisor.flv"
        });
    },
    swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/2.1.0/js",
    supplied: "flv"
});
});
```